# SimpleDateFormat return 1 hour why?

Tags: android, parsing, date, simpledateformat

I have SimpleDateFormat.

```
Date vrcTime;
SimpleDateFormat vrcCurrentTimeTextValue;
vrcTime.setTime (0);
vrcTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
vrcCurrentTimeTextValue =  vrcTimeFormat.format (vrcTime);
```

Why does my SimpleDateFormat returns 1 hour even though the time is 0 ?

Comment: use vrcTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT")); before vrcCurrentTimeTextValue =  vrcTimeFormat.format (vrcTime);

Comment: Central European Time (UTC +01:00)

Comment: @ArturSiwek and here is your hour: (UTC +01:00). The date 0 represents 1.1.1970, 0:00 UTC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are living in a GMT+1 time zone and unless you specify a different one, your formatter will pick your current one, so it considers 0 hours as GMT and as you are in GMT+1, it outputs 1 hour.
So add

```
vrcTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

i.e. rewrite your code as

```
Date vrcTime;
SimpleDateFormat vrcCurrentTimeTextValue;
vrcTime.setTime (0);
vrcTimeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat ("HH:mm:ss");
vrcTimeFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
vrcCurrentTimeTextValue =  vrcTimeFormat.format (vrcTime);
```